# images looks upside down in browser while in image editor looks perfect

Tags: image, imageview

i am having strange issue.

check this images.

http://project.demotestserver.com/card/spider-web-in-vines.jpg

http://project.demotestserver.com/card/thomas.jpg

http://project.demotestserver.com/card/Storm-cloud.jpg

just **save** these images and open it in **image editor** it looks perfect perfect .

in browser these images looks rotated while for the image editor it looks perfect.

due to these issue images looks rotated on my site. how to fix this thing?
if i will rotate images it will look perfect in browser while rotated in editor and desktops. for mobile it looks rotated as actual.

what is the solution of it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't look rotated to me on my system.  Perhaps you need to strip out EXIF data that contains orientation information?

Information on the problems caused by EXIF orientation tags:  http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2012/07/28/exif-orientation-handling-is-a-ghetto/

Comment: did you check that images in browser? and in image editor. ? in browser it looks rotated not only for me but for everyone.

Comment: I looked at them in a browser (Firefox 25, Linux).  When I bring them up in GIMP, it asks me a question of whether I want to rotate the image to "standard orientation," which tells me there's an EXIF orientation tag in there.  If I decline, the image looks correct. If I say yes, the image comes up rotated.

Comment: how to fix these issue? what should i do now?

Comment: What software do you have available to you for manipulating images?  GIMP is free to download and run, BTW.  ( www.gimp.org )

Comment: i am not able to use it . i am using xp sp2 . is it possible with php?

Comment: I found this link that suggests you can use PHP with ImageMagick to do so:    http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageorientation.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43009/discussion-between-jack-torris-and-joe-z)

Comment: @JackTorris : Unfortunately, it's very late here and I need to go to bed soon.  Good luck, though.